# Jmeter. TestScriptRecorder требует сертификат

Tags: jmeter

Установил сгенерированный jmeter сертификат в Доверенные корневые центры сертификации, но всё TestScriptRecorder всё равно просит установить сертификат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

На скриншоте - сообщение об успешном создании сертификата. Если запись идёт, проблемы нет; так и должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

Сертификат действует 7 дней, и при старте записи сертификат обновляется, если он устарёл, о чем и предупреждает [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

Вот здесь подробнее описано, [как установить CA сертификат JMeter в браузер](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)